# Method of characteristics inhomogeneous nonlinear wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Solve $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x$ subject to the initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$.

I let $\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , $\dfrac{dx}{ds}=u$ , $\dfrac{du}{ds}=x$ and the initial conditions become: $t=0$ , $x=\xi$ and $u=f(\xi)$ when $s=0$ .

I believe this leads to $t=s$ , but I am unsure how to deal with $\dfrac{dx}{ds}=u$ and $\dfrac{du}{ds}=x$ .

Comment: sorry i cant see how to make the math text larger

Comment: I believe you should have a look at the Burger's equation. The way it is being solved will help you understand this one.

Comment: I could not see how to do this as burger's equation is = 0 and my equation is equal to x. This means that u is not constant and therefore I cannot see how to use the solution to burgers equation to help solve my equation.

Comment: Studying the Burger's equation, as @user88595 suggest, will not only help you to derive the solution, but also to understand how it behaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDE is quasilinear, meaning it migh not have a *classic* solution for all  time $t$. That said, we know that the quasilinear equation 
$$
a\big(x,t,u(x,t)\big) u_x(x,t) + b\big(x,t,u(x,t)\big)u_t(x,t) = c\big(x,t,u(x,t)\big)
$$
where $a,\,b,\,c \in C^1$ with data $\mathcal{C}(\xi) = \big(x(\xi), t(\xi), u(\xi)\big) \in C^1$ and with
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \frac{dx}{d\xi} & a \\ \frac{dt}{d\xi} & b\end{vmatrix} \neq 0
$$
has a unique solution near $\mathcal{C}$ given by
\begin{align}
 \frac{d x}{d \eta} &= a  & x\big|_{\eta = 0}&= x(\xi)\\
 \frac{d t}{d \eta} &= b  & t\big|_{\eta = 0}&= t(\xi)\\
 \frac{d u}{d \eta} &= c  & u\big|_{\eta = 0}&= u(\xi)\\
\end{align}

In your case, $\mathcal{C}(\xi) = \big(\xi,0,f(\xi)\big)$. Near $\eta \sim 0$ 
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \frac{dx}{d\xi} & a \\ \frac{dt}{d\xi} & b\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & u \\ 0 & 1\end{vmatrix} = 1
$$
and the solution is unique near the initial condition. Now,

\begin{align}
 \frac{d x}{d \eta} &= u  & x\big|_{\eta = 0}&= \xi\\
 \frac{d t}{d \eta} &= 1    & t\big|_{\eta = 0}&= 0\\
 \frac{d u}{d \eta} &= x    & u\big|_{\eta = 0}&= f(\xi)\\
\end{align}
has as solution
$$
t = \eta, \quad u = f(\xi)\cosh \eta + \xi \sinh \eta, \quad x =f(\xi) \sinh \eta + \xi \cosh \eta.
$$
and the characteristics are given by the equation
$$
t= \text{arctanh}\left(\frac{x - \xi}{f(\xi)}\right)
$$
**(you have to be carefull while inverting $\tanh t$)**.

Depending on the behavior of $f$, if the characteristics can meet. If the do, there will be a shock and the classical solution will cease to exist. We can see this by studying the transformation
$$
(x,t) \longrightarrow (\xi,\eta).
$$
The change of variables will be invertible iif
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \partial_\xi x & \partial_\eta x \\ \partial_\xi t & \partial_\eta t \end{vmatrix} = f'(\xi) \sinh\eta + \cosh \eta \neq 0
$$
meaning there is no solution when 
$$
f'(\xi) \sinh\eta + \cosh \eta = 0
$$ 
or, inverting the transformation, the solution will develop a shock at time
$$
t = -\text{arctanh}\left(f'(\xi)\right),
$$
and the profile of $f(x)$ is crucial in the shock development. This is why, if you want to understand how this works, you have to study the Burger's equation, as suggested by [user88595](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668664/method-of-characteristics-inhomogeneous-nonlinear-wave-equation#comment1405597_668664).

In the region where no shock has developed (might be all the domain), the solution is given by
$$
u(x,t) = f\big(\xi(x,t)\big)\cosh t + \xi(x,t) \sinh t
$$
where $\xi(x,t)$ is determined by inverting
$$
x = f(\xi) \sinh t + \xi \cosh t,
$$
which can be written in implicit form as
$$
f\big(x \cosh t - u(x,t) \sinh t\big) = u(x,t) \cosh t - x \sinh t
$$

Answer (score 4):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{dx}{ds}=u\\\dfrac{du}{ds}=x\end{cases}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d^2x}{ds^2}=x$

$x=C_1\sinh s+C_2\cosh s$

$\therefore u=C_1\cosh s+C_2\sinh s$

Hence $\begin{cases}x=C_1\sinh s+C_2\cosh s\\u=C_1\cosh s+C_2\sinh s\end{cases}$

$x(0)=x_0$ , $u(0)=F(x_0)$ :

$\begin{cases}C_1=F(x_0)\\C_2=x_0\end{cases}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}x=F(x_0)\sinh s+x_0\cosh s\\u=F(x_0)\cosh s+x_0\sinh s\end{cases}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}x_0=x\cosh s-u\sinh s=x\cosh t-u\sinh t\\F(x_0)=u\cosh s-x\sinh s=u\cosh t-x\sinh t\end{cases}$

Hence $u\cosh t-x\sinh t=F(x\cosh t-u\sinh t)$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$F(x)=f(x)$

$\therefore u\cosh t-x\sinh t=f(x\cosh t-u\sinh t)$